# React Forward Ref not working as with Custom Compoent

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-forwardref

I need to wrap my custom component in the Material UI Tooltip. I believe I'm using ForwardRefs properly, however the tooltip does not appear at all regardless of events (hover,click, etc)

```
const MyComp = ({ buttonRef }) => {
    return <button ref={buttonRef}>this does not work</button>;
};

const MyCompForwardRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <MyComp {...props} buttonRef={ref} />;
});

const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <button ref={ref}>this also does not work</button>
));

const Page = () => (
  <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
    <div style={{ margin: "10px" }}>
    <Tooltip title="23456789">
      //not working
      <MyCompForwardRef />
    </Tooltip>
  </div>
  <div style={{ margin: "10px" }}>
  <Tooltip title="23456789">
    //not working
    <FancyButton />
  </Tooltip>
  </div>
  <div style={{ margin: "10px" }}>
    <Tooltip title="23456789">
      <button>this works</button>
    </Tooltip>
  </div>
</div>);
```

Here is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-card-styling-example-forked-9tqod?file=/src/index.js:438-914

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to update all versions, especially MUI version.

Second, you need to pass the props too, so it will apply the Tooltip styles and events to the inner component.

> Everything mentioned in [MUI docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs)

```
const MyComp = ({ buttonRef, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <button {...props} ref={buttonRef}>
      work
    </button>
  );
};

const MyCompForwardRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <MyComp {...props} buttonRef={ref} />;
});

const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <button {...props} ref={ref}>
      work
    </button>
  );
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-forwardref-tooltip-issue-forked-8u5vm?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks, since my custom components already has quite a bit of props. I guess I will need to separate out the props passed into the forwardRef, and pass those into the element receiving the ref correct?

Comment: This is it.  I wish I would have found this answer hours ago.  There's nothing in the MUI docs that explicitly states you should forward the props as well as the ref.  To be more explicit, this will overwrite the aria-describedby, className, onBlur, onFocus, onMouseLeave, onMouseOver, onTouchEnd, onTouchStart, and title props of your child.